# What is the meaning of these lines from Bram Stoker's Dracula?

Tags: meaning

> The Bride maidens rejoice the eyes that wait the coming of the bride. But when the bride draweth nigh, then the maidens shine not to the eyes that are filled.

The above lines are uttered by the zoophagous patient Reinfield.

If one were to guess that Dracula is the Bride and the Bride maidens are all the people other than Reinfield, ?

Comment: https://literature.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for an extended interpretation and thus belongs on Literature.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an allusion to Christ in the Bible.

See [John 3:29](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%203:29)

> The bride belongs to the bridegroom. The friend who attends the
>   bridegroom waits and listens for him, and is full of joy when he hears
>   the bridegroom’s voice. That joy is mine, and it is now complete.

However the senses have been altered. Reinfield is preparing the way for Dracula, as John the Baptist prepared the way for Christ.

The allusion has swapped hearing for vision.

[The Theology of Dracula](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WpSAkij0LUAC&pg=PA121&lpg=PA121&dq=%22then%20the%20maidens%20shine%20not%20to%20the%20eyes%20that%20are%20filled.%22&source=bl&ots=b11XU_mf8r&sig=vcNdNl11ZhYjx3Qu_5b6uZz_eu4&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22then%20the%20maidens%20shine%20not%20to%20the%20eyes%20that%20are%20filled.%22&f=false): Reading the Book of Stoker as Sacred Text, has this to say on the subject:

> Speaking as a Baptist-like figure, Reinfield transforms John 3:29's
>   metaphor of a marriage scene by substituting senses - sight for sound,
>   watching for harking - and focus - feminine for masculine, deception
>   for joy...

[Gradesaver's study guide](http://www.gradesaver.com/dracula/study-guide/summary-chapter-6-10), has some further analysis:

> Renfield's ravings and his new position as Dracula's henchmen continue
>   to develop the perverse parallels between Dracula and Christ. Much of
>   Renfield's language borrows and reshapes scripture: "The bride-maidens
>   rejoice the eyes that wait the coming of the bride; but when the bride
>   draweth nigh, then the maidens shine not to the eyes that are filled."
>   Renfield becomes an evil version of John the Baptist, one who prepares
>   the way for a greater Lord. And at Carfax, as at Dracula's ancestral
>   castle in Transylvania, the Count sleeps in a ruined chapel. He turns
>   a Christian place of worship into a lair of evil, instating himself as
>   the chapel's new Lord.

Answer (score 1):

Spagirl is correct. "Nigh" means near. The analogy begins with the people waiting for the bride to arrive (the eyes that wait) who rejoice in the appearance of the bridesmaids, initially, because they foretell the coming of the bride. But once the bride appears, the bridesmaids are forgotten (shine not) to the people in audience (the eyes that are filled by the bride).

To complete the analogy, Renfield had been obsessed with his dark pets--spiders and the rest--which, like bridesmaids, foretold the coming of the main attraction (Dracula). Renfield says to the attendant in this chapter that "the master is at hand." When Dr. Seward asks Renfield about his pets, Renfield says, "I don't care a pin about them." Renfield (the eyes that wait the coming of the bride) no longer rejoices in the bridemaidens (spiders, etc.). They no longer attract his attention (shine not), because his eyes are filled with the bride who draweth nigh/near (Dracula).

With this analogy/metaphor, Renfield is simply explaining that his dark pets were only interesting to him because they foretold the coming of the dark master. Now that the master is at hand, his pets no longer "shine."

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It means:

People attending a wedding see bridesmaids and get all excited because it suggests the bride is coming. But when the bride doesn't show up, then the bridesmaids are no longer anything special.

Comment: 'The bride draweth nigh' means 'the bride comes near', it is when the bride *does* show up that the bridesmaids seem less of an attraction.